# Getting an error while I use precompiled CFC from Adobe CF in Lucee

Tags: java, encryption, coldfusion, cfc, lucee

I am using Lucee server, and I have a CFC file precompiled in Adobe CF and recently we moved from ACF to Lucee. Here I am facing an issue to create an object of it.

The code related to it is placed within another CFC within the same directory and looks like this:

```cfml
<cfset myEncryption = createObject("component", "encryption") />
```

Below is the stack trace. Can anybody suggest me how to fix this issue? What settings and configurations are required for it to work?

> lucee.runtime.exp.NativeException: coldfusion/runtime/UDFMethod at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at lucee.commons.lang.PhysicalClassLoader._loadClass(PhysicalClassLoader.java:201) at lucee.commons.lang.PhysicalClassLoader.loadClass(PhysicalClassLoader.java:182) at lucee.runtime.MappingImpl.getPhysicalClass(MappingImpl.java:276) at lucee.runtime.PageSourceImpl._compile(PageSourceImpl.java:449) at lucee.runtime.PageSourceImpl.compile(PageSourceImpl.java:413) at lucee.runtime.PageSourceImpl.loadPhysical(PageSourceImpl.java:346) at lucee.runtime.PageSourceImpl.loadPageThrowTemplateException(PageSourceImpl.java:237) at lucee.runtime.PageSourceImpl.loadPage(PageSourceImpl.java:1013) at lucee.runtime.component.ComponentLoader._search(ComponentLoader.java:219) at lucee.runtime.component.ComponentLoader._search(ComponentLoader.java:117) at lucee.runtime.component.ComponentLoader.searchComponent(ComponentLoader.java:79) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.loadComponent(PageContextImpl.java:3247) at lucee.runtime.functions.other.CreateObject.doComponent(CreateObject.java:148) at lucee.runtime.functions.other.CreateObject.call(CreateObject.java:70) at lucee.runtime.functions.other.CreateObject.call(CreateObject.java:49) at member_cfc$cf.udfCall3(/cfc/Member.cfc:1410) at member_cfc$cf.udfCall(/cfc/Member.cfc) at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106) at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344) at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:217) at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:684) at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572) at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1911) at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:787) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1747) at html.loggedin_cfm$cf.call(/html/loggedin.cfm:181) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:1034) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:926) at lucee.runtime.listener.ModernAppListener._onRequest(ModernAppListener.java:217) at lucee.runtime.listener.MixedAppListener.onRequest(MixedAppListener.java:44) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.execute(PageContextImpl.java:2460) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._execute(PageContextImpl.java:2450) at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.executeCFML(PageContextImpl.java:2421) at lucee.runtime.engine.Request.exe(Request.java:45) at lucee.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl._service(CFMLEngineImpl.java:1179) at lucee.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.serviceCFML(CFMLEngineImpl.java:1125) at lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineWrapper.serviceCFML(CFMLEngineWrapper.java:97) at lucee.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet.service(CFMLServlet.java:51) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:433) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: coldfusion/runtime/UDFMethod ... 63 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class [coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod] is invalid or doesn't exist at lucee.commons.lang.PhysicalClassLoader.findClass(PhysicalClassLoader.java:161) at lucee.commons.lang.PhysicalClassLoader.loadClass(PhysicalClassLoader.java:142) at lucee.commons.lang.PhysicalClassLoader.loadClass(PhysicalClassLoader.java:125) at lucee.commons.lang.PhysicalClassLoader.loadClass(PhysicalClassLoader.java:119) ... 63 more Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\inetpub\alhpa.boul.com\WEB-INF\lucee\cfclasses\CFC__inetpub_alhpa_boul_com_cfc6280\coldfusion\runtime\UDFMethod.class at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source) at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source) at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(Unknown Source) at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Unknown Source) at lucee.commons.io.res.type.file.FileResource.getInputStream(FileResource.java:243) at lucee.commons.io.IOUtil.copy(IOUtil.java:190) at lucee.commons.lang.PhysicalClassLoader.findClass(PhysicalClassLoader.java:157) ... 66 more

Comment: You should also provide the code you use to create an object of the CFC. Also it's not clear to me what you mean by "encrypted file in HEX code". Could you please clarify what kind of file that is? It sounds like it is some binary file and not a CFC.

Comment: My CFC file in encrypted file ( Like java class)  , recently we moved our code to Lucee, so it did not worked.

Comment: That's what I suspected. So it's a compiled file. Again, please share the code where you're trying to instantiate an object from it. And you should also share where you've placed that file because the error message says that it cannot be found. Without that information it's hard to provide a useful answer.

Comment: My File encrytion.cfc is under the path C:\inetpub\alhpa.boul.com\cfc and I am calling from C:\inetpub\alhpa.boul.com\cfc\member.cfc as below 
<cfset myEncryption = createObject("component", "encryption") />

Also I added full error dump

Comment: `My CFC file in encrypted file ( Like java class) , recently we moved our code to Lucee, so it did not worked?` Do you mean you [*compiled*](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/deploying-coldfusion-applications.html#Usingthecfcompileutility) your cfml source code with Adobe CF and then tried to run the *compiled* code  under Lucee?

Comment: @SOS, Yes That was compiled code from Adobe CF and we are tried to run under Lucee

Comment: @MohanRaju The info that you are trying to use a precompiled CFC from Adobe CF in Lucee is an important piece of information your question is missing. The same applies to the code you wrote in one of the previous comments. So please edit your question and add all the info you shared here in the comments! Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the point about compiled code, I'm not sure it's possible to run code compiled with Adobe ColdFusion in Lucee. Isn't it possible for you to use the source CFC?

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian Zartner for clarify on this. I update my question here correctly as suggested.

Comment: (Edit) Did you see the last question, i.e. "*Isn't it possible for you to use the source?*" (... I don't know if it's supported either. My gut says no, but that's not based on anything official, just a feeling)

Comment: This has been resolved.

The code which complied from ACF wont work on Lucee server. We should get original source code to lucee and get it complied in lucee version and then use this complied file. Now removed original source code file.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it is not possible to instantiate objects in Lucee from a CFC that got precompiled in Adobe ColdFusion.

If possible, you should rather use the source CFC instead of the compiled version. This will allow you to further debug what's the root cause of the error.

Comment: Yes. We could not use CFC that got precompiled in ACF.

This has been resolved.  Finally I got the original source code and copied to lucee and get it complied in lucee version and then use this complied file. Now removed original source code file

Thank you all for your inputs and involment